# HTTP selector of a link (xpath or css)

Tags: python, html, css, xpath

I'm trying to grab the `href` element of each shoe in this site:

http://www.soccerpro.com/Clearance-Soccer-Shoes-c168/

But I can't get the proper selectors right.

```
response.xpath('.//*[@class="newnav itemnamelink"]')
[]
```

Anyone know how would I do this in xpath or css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required links generated dynamically, so you wouldn't be able to scrape them from `HTML` source that you get like `requests.get("http://www.soccerpro.com/Clearance-Soccer-Shoes-c168/")`

You might use `selenium` to get required values via browser session:

```
from selenium import webdriver as web
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = web.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.soccerpro.com/Clearance-Soccer-Shoes-c168/')
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='getproductdisplay-innertable']")))
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="newnav itemnamelink"]')]
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without selenium? I don't want to slow down my web app. I'm doing an app that searches over a thousand different shoes links from multiple websites.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it.

Comment: ah.. apparently it also needs to open the web browser for it to get the address, similar to selenium

Comment: Unfortunately you can interact with `JavaScript` in this way only... To speed-up `selenium` script execution you can use `PhantomJS` headless browser instead of `chromedriver`

Comment: Is there a way to stop it from opening up the browser?

Comment: No. The problem is that initially http://www.soccerpro.com/Clearance-Soccer-Shoes-c168/ is just an empty page. When browser opens the page it parses `HTML` and executes all found `JavaScript`. That's the only way how `table` with required links can be created...